# Post-Increment as Index Confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, post-increment

I would rather say this to the point by showing the code.

*Feel free to make this post as duplicate if it already has the answer to it (because I haven't found one)*

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{
    int test=3;
    int *arr=(int*)malloc (5*sizeof (int));
    for (int x=0; x<5; x++) *(arr+x)=x+1;
    *(arr+(test++))=999;
    for (int x=0; x<5; x++) printf ("%d ", *(arr+x));

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 999 5
```

The question is, there I say test++ which means test will be incremented to 4 right? But why `999` is inserted to the index [3] instead of [4]?

From what I know, `test` should be incremented before `999` assigned to `arr`. Is there any explanation for this piece of code? (Is it different? Because it results in the same thing when I thought it should be different)

```
*(arr+(test++))=999;
*(arr+test)=999; test++;

/*
Or,
arr[test++]=999;        //999 goes to [3] instead of [4]
arr[test]=999; test++;  //The right syntax should be like this right?
*/
```

Btw, pre-increment works just fine like if I do `arr[++test]=999`, `999` will be assigned to index [4].

*I'm sorry if the way I speak is too messy, ask anything if you think something is missing from my explanation and I hope with this post, other people who also got confused can understand it.*

Comment: how did you get this output?

Comment: `*(arr+x)` is better written as `arr[x]`.

Comment: @P__J__ It was a typo, thank you for reminding, just realized. *I typed 1 2 3 4 999 5, it should be 1 2 3 999 5*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Pre-increment operator :** A pre-increment operator( `++i` ) is used to increment
>   the value of a variable before using it in a expression. In the
>   Pre-Increment, value is first incremented and then used inside the
>   expression.
>
> **Post-increment operator:** A post-increment operator ( `i++` ) is used to
>   increment the value of variable after executing expression completely
>   in which post increment is used. In the Post-Increment, value is first
>   used in a expression and then incremented.

So, in your case, the `test++` will first return the value, that is 3. Then the it will increment. Thus, the `arr[test++]` goes to index 3 instead of 4. If you would have done like this - `arr[++test] = 999`, then first the value of test would have been increased to the value 4 and then that would have been used as the index in the statement. That's the main difference between post-increment and pre-increment.

Hope this clears your doubt !

Comment: So you mean `test++` simply means `test` will be incremented **after** something is done with it right?

Comment: @LastSecond959 correct ! First it's current value will be returned/used and only then it will be incremented. So `arr[test++] = 999;`  is equivalent to `arr[test] = 999; test +=1;`

Comment: Let's say `test=2` and `res=(test++)+7`, printing `res` will show `9` instead of `10` and if I want to make `10`, I can change it to either `++test` or `test+=1` and that being said, the conclusion is that `test+=1` is actually the same as `++test`, correct?

Comment: It is not correct to assert that prefix/postfix increment operators increment the value before or after producing is value, and it is particularly wrong to assert that, for postfix increment, the increment is “after executing expression completely.” For the postfix operator, the C standard says the value produced is that of the operand, and, **as a side effect**, the value is incremented. It does not say whether this increment occurs during the expression evaluation or later (or even before, as long as the correct value is produced in the expression).

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thx for explaining it. Tbh, I think 70% of my programming knowledge is not from my college :D. And I also not a reader.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I didn't understand your statement completely. Is it not the case that for a variable `i`, the post-increment - `i++` will increment `i` but return the original value of `i` in the expression we are using it in? If not, is there any example ?

Comment: @Abhishek: In `i++`, the value used is that of `i` before an increment. At some time, `i` is also incremented. This increment may occur at various times. It is incorrect to state that it occurs after the expression in which `i` occurs is completed. It is even incorrect to say that it occurs as an atomic operation. For example, `i = 3; printf("%d\n", i + i++);` can yield 6 because the increment occurs after the `printf`, it can yield `7` because the increment occurs after the value was produced for `i++` and before it was used for the first `i`, and it can also have undefined behavior.

Comment: As an example, consider `int128_t i = ((int128_t) 1 << 64) - 1; printf("%" PRId128 "\n", i + i++);`. If the hardware does not have built-in 128-bit integer instructions, the compiler has to implement the `int128_t` type using smaller. To increment `i`, it has to increment the low 64-bit word and then add the carry bit to the high 64-bit word. So two instruction are required. It could be that one instruction comes before the first `i` (and wraps the low word) and the other instruction comes after it, resulting in `i + i++` acting as if it were `0 + i++`.

Comment: So, the working of post-increment operator is compiler-dependent and the time when increment occurs depends on how the compiler is designed ? Or is this undefined behavior altogether and may happen differently, at different times, on same compiler as well?

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce the result

```
1 2 3 4 999 5
```

Running your program I got

```
1 2 3 999 5
```

I think there is a typo in your question.

As for the question

> The question is, there I say test++ which means test will be
>   incremented to 4 right? But why 999 is inserted to the index [3]
>   instead of [4]?

then according to the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand**.
>   As a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

So you may consider this statement

```
*(arr+(test++))=999
```

like

```
*(arr+(test))=999
++test;
```

Comment: Yes, I typed 1 2 3 4 999 5 by mistake, I just realized it after I read @P__J__'s comment. Thx anyway. I just spammed the numbers (habit, sorry XD).

Answer (score 0):

what is confusing you. The result is: 1 2 3 999 5  using gcc.

https://godbolt.org/z/fgm5Xg

Comment: I was asking the process (how it was done, how it works), not the result.

"The question is, there I say test++ which means test will be incremented to 4 right? But why 999 is inserted to the index [3] instead of [4]?"

Comment: @LastSecond959 but the result shown in your question is wrong - the question does not make sense. BTW post and preincrement operatiors are explained very well in any C book.

Comment: Oh, I see, I just realized I made a typo there, thanks for reminding.